# Understanding how XMLHttpRequest sends data to a server

Tags: php, http, post, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I haven't understand data transfer to the server completely. Which ways do I have? When I started learning PHP, I thought there are two ways called `GET` which encrypts data in the URL and `POST` which sends data in another way to the server. I didn't know where exactly, though.

Now I want to learn about RESTful server backends, and I learned that `GET` and `POST` are just request methods, among others like `PUT` and `DELETE`, which doesn't seem to have anything to do with *how data is transferred* to the server.

Moreover, I read that additional data can be sent in the HTTP header. Is this how `POST` actually sends its data or is there even a difference?

I would like to either read POST data regardless of the request method using PHP's `$_POST` array, but this doesn't work. On the other hand, when I try to manually parse the header information from `php://input`, I cannot see POST data. Could someone please explain to me where data is transferred in the different cases?

My goal is to get parameters from the client regardless of content type, which may be `form-data`, `json` or something other, and request method. How can I do this in PHP? Requests will be sent using JQuery's AJAX functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain how does http work using `nc`
http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc

**GET**

`$ nc -l 8888` to start a dummy server listen at 8888

send a GET request using jQuery (impl via XHR)

```
$.get("http://localhost:8888", { a :1 ,b: 2})
```

nc would print what XHR sent to server to stdout

```
$nc -l 8888
GET /?a=1&b=2&_=1383234919249 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Origin: http://stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710815/understanding-how-xmlhttprequest-sends-data-to-a-server
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
```

thus, PHP parse `GET /?a=1&b=2&_=1383234919249` into `$_GET`

**POST**

using `nc` to recording POST

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 7
Accept: */*
Origin: http://stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
DNT: 1
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710815/understanding-how-xmlhttprequest-sends-data-to-a-server
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4

a=1&b=2
```

here you can see `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
,which tell the http body sent by browser is form encoded

as a result, PHP parse `a=1&b=2` in to array `$_POST`

**WHY `php://input` can't see POST BODY**

according to http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

`php://input` is a stream and can be read only once

below is from php doc

> Note: A stream opened with php://input can only be read once; the
>   stream does not support seek operations. However, depending on the
>   SAPI implementation, it may be possible to open another php://input
>   stream and restart reading. This is only possible if the request body
>   data has been saved. Typically, this is the case for POST requests,
>   but not other request methods, such as PUT or PROPFIND.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. After reading that I have some questions remaining. So only `GET` is special, all other request methods encode their data in the request content? How can I read the request content to decode the data (according to the specified content type)? You talk about a post body, is there only one HTTP body or one for each request type?

Comment: @danijar `Content-Type` in the header. HTTP body are the rest data after HTTP header, POST and PUT have body, but they are the same. in PHP they are all stream( php://input )

Comment: Okay this is clearer now. Can I provide a custom HTTP body regardless of request method, for example sending JSON encoded information with a `GET` request? I wonder whether there is a constraint on this or not.

Comment: @danijar if sending GET to server, server would NOT read your HTTP body. however, you can put anything (include json) you want in the POST/PUT body

Comment: Is this the same case for not only `POST` and `PUT`, but also `DELETE`, and even custom named request methods?